# How can tiny-invariant.js be so big?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, profiling, source-maps

I am trying to optimize the size of my react app chunks. I analyzed them using:

`source-map-explorer 'build/static/js/*.js`

The result is the image below and it show that the `tiny-invariant.js` is taking 774KB of space. It doesn't make sense to me. How can a lib that takes [12.2kB unpacked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiny-invariant) show up as taking 774KB?

What can be wrong? Is source-map-explorer buggy? Right now that's my main explanation.

[image: Output of source-map-explorer]

Comment: Yep, I have the exact same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `source-map-explorer` is NOT correct in this case.

My solution was to compare the `source-map-explorer` result with the one from `webpack-bundle-analyzer`:

```
> npm run build -- --stats
> npx webpack-bundle-analyzer ./build/bundle-stats.json
```

*(The feature is currently undocumented (documentation was removed), because the CRA team find the labelling of webpack-bundle-analyzer misleading, see: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4563)*

In `webpack-bundle-analyzer` result I found that the same size was actually from:

- `moment-timezone/data/packed/latest.json`.

I guess `source-map-explorer` doesn't work well with json files.